# Find WebForms Parent Control of Type

Tags: webforms, controls

I want to find the parent control of a specific type and I don't know its ID.

The page can look like this:

```
- MasterPage
    - HomePage
        - SomeControl
            - TargetControl
                - SomeOtherControl
                    - ThisControl
```

And I want to get the `ThisControl` parent of type `TargetControl`:

```
Control targetControl = thisControl.FindParentControl(typeof(TargetControl));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy with an extension method, recursively checking the parent controls type.

```
public static Control FindParentControl(this Control control, Type parentType)
{
    while(control != null)
        if (control.Parent.GetType() == parentType)
            return control.Parent;
        else
            control = control.Parent;

    return null;
}
```